# Is there a coding difference between .IPA and .APK?

Tags: apk, ipa

Okay so I know the file types are different, but I wanted to know if all I did was take the code from a .IPA would it work in an APK.

Comment: Just like you can't take a .app and repackage it into a Linux ELF, you can't take a .ipa and repackage it into an Android APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are different formats of executable files for different hardware and software platforms. The only option to have one source code is to use some kind of SDK, which suports both platforms. Such SDK hides from you specific API of each platform and provides one more level of abstraction.

Comment: okay thanks, the reason that i was asking was because I wanted to take a game thats made for iphone/ipod and play it on my phone because it was fun